# How to save a parsnip model fit (from ranger)?

Tags: r, tidymodels, r-ranger, r-parsnip

I have a parsnip model (from ranger), roughly from [here](https://www.tidymodels.org/start/resampling/#data):

```
# install.packages("tidymodels")

data(cells, package = "modeldata")

rf_mod <- 
  rand_forest(trees = 100) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")

set.seed(123)
cell_split <- initial_split(cells %>% select(-case), strata = class)

cell_train <- training(cell_split)

rf_fit <- 
  rf_mod %>% 
  fit(class ~ ., data = cell_train)
```

```
> class(rf_fit)
[1] "_ranger"   "model_fit"
```

How do I save it to disk so that I can load it at a later time?

I tried `dput`, and that gets an error:

```
dput(rf_fit, file="rf_fit.R")
rf_fit2 <- dget("rf_fit.R")
Error in missing_arg() : could not find function "missing_arg"
```

It's true, the `model_fit.R` file has a couple of `missing_arg` calls in it, which appears to be some sort of way to mark missing args.  However, that's a side line.  I don't need to use dput, I just want to be able to save and load a model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this option. `save()` and `load()` functions allow you to store the model and then inkove it again. Here the code:

```
data(cells, package = "modeldata")

rf_mod <- 
  rand_forest(trees = 100) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger") %>% 
  set_mode("classification")

set.seed(123)
cell_split <- initial_split(cells %>% select(-case), strata = class)

cell_train <- training(cell_split)

rf_fit <- 
  rf_mod %>% 
  fit(class ~ ., data = cell_train)

#Export option
save(rf_fit,file='Mymod.RData')
load('Mymod.RData')
```

The other option would be using `saveRDS()` to save the model and then use `readRDS()` to load it but it requires to be allocated in an object:

```
#Export option 2
saveRDS(rf_fit, file = "Mymod.rds")
# Restore the object
rf_fit <- readRDS(file = "Mymod.rds")
```

Comment: Doh! I've used `save` many times, but late on a Friday it didn't occur to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For others that may come across this post in the future:

Some model fits in R, including several that parsnip supports as a modeling backend, require native serialization methods to be saved and reloaded in a new R session properly. `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()` will do the trick most of the time, though [fall short](https://github.com/rstudio/bundle) for model objects from packages that require native serialization.

The folks from the tidymodels team put together a new package, [bundle](https://github.com/rstudio/bundle), to provide a consistent interface for native serialization of model objects. The `bundle()` verb prepares a model object for serialization, and then you can safely `saveRDS()` + `readRDS()` and pass between R sessions as you wish, and then `unbundle()` in the new session. With a parsnip model fit `mod`:

```
mod_bundle <- bundle(mod)
saveRDS(mod_bundle, file = "path/to/file.rds")

# in a new R session:
mod_bundle <- readRDS("path/to/file.rds")
mod_new <- unbundle(mod_bundle)
```

Answer (score 0):

As Duck mentioned, `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()` can be used to save/load any R object. Also `save()` & `load()` can be used for the same purpose. There are many online discussions/blogs comparing the two approaches.